# How can I change the color of the text separately with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-hooks, use-state, textcolor

I want the links to work separately

The colors change together now

This is my code

```
const ChatHeader = ({ location: { pathname } }) => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("black");
  const [isBlack, setIsBlack] = useState(true);
  const changeColor = (e) => {
    setIsBlack(!isBlack);
    setColor(isBlack ? "#CCCCCC" : "black");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <ChatTexts>
        <ChatText
          current={pathname === "/chats"}
          style={{ color: color }}
          onClick={changeColor}
        >
          <ChatLinks to="/chats">채팅</ChatLinks>
        </ChatText>
        <OpenChateText
          current={pathname === "/openchats"}
          style={{ color: color }}
          onClick={changeColor}
        >
          <ChatLinks to="/openchats">오픈채팅</ChatLinks>
        </OpenChateText>
      </ChatTexts>
    </>
  );
};
```

How can ChatText and OpenChateText colors be changed differently?

If I enter the "/chats" link, I would like the "/chats" letter color to be black, and the "/openchats" link letter color to be gray.

Conversely, when you enter the "/openchats" link, I want the "/openchats" link letter color to be black and the "/chats" link letter color to be gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ditch the state and `onClick` handlers/callbacks and use the `pathname` to derive the "active" color directly.

```
const ChatHeader = ({ location: { pathname } }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ChatTexts>
        <ChatText
          current={pathname === "/chats"}
          style={{ color: pathname === "/chats" ? "black" : "#cccccc" }}
        >
          <ChatLinks to="/chats">채팅</ChatLinks>
        </ChatText>
        <OpenChateText
          current={pathname === "/openchats"}
          style={{ color: pathname === "/openchats" ? "black" : "#cccccc" }}
        >
          <ChatLinks to="/openchats">오픈채팅</ChatLinks>
        </OpenChateText>
      </ChatTexts>
    </>
  );
};
```

An minor optimization to be more **DRY**

```
const ChatHeader = ({ location: { pathname } }) => {
  const getStyle = (path) => ({
    color: pathname === path ? "black" : "#cccccc",
  });
  return (
    <>
      <ChatTexts>
        <ChatText
          current={pathname === "/chats"}
          style={getStyle("/chats")}
        >
          <ChatLinks to="/chats">채팅</ChatLinks>
        </ChatText>
        <OpenChateText
          current={pathname === "/openchats"}
          style={getStyle("/openchats")}
        >
          <ChatLinks to="/openchats">오픈채팅</ChatLinks>
        </OpenChateText>
      </ChatTexts>
    </>
  );
};
```